# Pages in Microsoft Word suddenly disappear

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010, file-corruption

I was using Microsoft Word 2010, but suddenly the pages changed to what's shown in the picture (multiple small pages with no text on them). I can't access some of the pages. I'm running Windows 7. [image]

```
by clicking gray area
```

[image]
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz11v320mym09yx/sample.docx?dl=0)

Comment: Which version of Word? Which OS? Does it happen to any file, or just one in particular? If it's just with one, did you try restoring a previous revision of that file to see if it works with that?

Comment: @slhck Microsoft word 2010, windows seven. now it happen just to this file. and when its text copy it to anther document, this problem is still exist. but by copying its content to wordpad , i can see all the content correctly.

Comment: @slhck i didn't try to restore it. how can i do that?

Comment: After you paste the text to Wordpad, can you paste the contents of Wordpad into a new Word document without issue? If so, this would lead me to believe the formatting is corrupt in the original Word file.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes it solved. but I don't know what cause this issue. it happened when i was writing in the word

Comment: Check  https://www.google.se/search?q=word+hidden+page   and maybe http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/getting-hidden-pages-with-i-use-section-break/140d5dd7-e4ef-46fe-92d3-99f2585cfde0

Comment: What happens if you double-click the grey space *between* the white page sections? Does your mouse pointer change when you point to this grey space?

Comment: @twisty I add the new image that shows what happened by clicking gray area

Comment: Does your mouse pointer change when you point to this grey space?

Comment: @Twisty i upload a sample file.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your files if you have **.asd** files in your **Autorecover file location**

Open you word document and go to **File -> Options -> Save**

[image]

You will find your Autorecover file location there. Copy the location and close your word document

Go to the location which you copied and check for **.asd** files if any available. Open .asd files with word and recover the file

If no .asd files no recovery files saved.

**Note**: Recovery files is based on recovery time as per your Autorecover configuration

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. but there was nor .asd file for given document.

Comment: I want to know what cause this problem. because i cant scroll down pages from that point.

Comment: Suspect your document may get corrupted